# Make extension using Cython, with a different name than the source file

Tags: python, gcc, cython

I know how to make C code from Python using `cythonize -o mymodule.c mymodule.py` or using the `cython` command. The resulting C file has to be compiled to an Python extension using gcc or any other C compiler, and I'm also able doing that. If I want it really simple, I just use `distutils`/`setuptools` and `python setup.py build_ext`.

But what I can't figure out is how to make an extension file (pyd/so) with a **DIFFERENT** name than the source file. I can't simply rename the file due to the fact that there has to be a function `PyInit_modulename` in the extension, and I can't change `modulename.pyd` to `_modulename.pyd`, that would require `PyInit__modulename` and throw this exeption:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit__modulename)
```

Basically it should be like this:

```
mymodule.py -> _mymodule.pyd
```

This avoids e.g. the import confusion if I have two files with the same name but a different ending (py/pyd/pyc/pyo/so/dll):

```
mydir/
  mymodule.py
  mymodule.pyd
```

Code:

```
from mymodule import func
func()
# Is this now from the extension or from the python code?
# And how to access tho other one?
```

What I need is:

```
mydir/
  mymodule.py
  _mymodule.pyd   <- Note the underscore!
```

Code:

```
import mymodule as script
script.func()
# Run the code from the python file

import _mymodule as extension
extension.func()
# Run code from the extension
```

But how on earth can I compile like this?

Thank you in advance!

---

*Just one thought I had: I think I need to start somewhere at the C code generation with cython.*

Comment: It seems that the only way to affect the module name is by changing the name of the cython file i.e. `_modulename.pyx`.

Comment: @J.J.Hakala - Yes, I already thought that after some days of research. I made a script for that, wich automatically saves the file in the temp dir to a given name and compiles the file

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your `setup.py`

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension

from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np # if it requires numpy

ext_modules = [Extension("desired_name",["original_name.pyx"])]

setup(
    name= 'Generic model class',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs = [np.get_include()], # only if it requires numpy
    ext_modules = ext_modules)
```

Comment: That doesn't not work, it throws an Import error due to the missing PyInit_original_name function. I already tried this before, it would be too easy!